# The normal vector field of hypersurface

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces

An affine algebraic hypersurface may be defined by an equation

$$F(x,y,z,w)=xy+xz-xyz+xyzw$$

and alevel surface in four-dimensional space is defined by an equation of the form $F(x, y, z,w) = c$.

> How can I find the normal vector field and  tangent vector field  of
>    hypersurface $F(x,y,z,w)$ ?
>
> What is the mathematical basis for  consider

$$N=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z},\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\right)$$
is normal vector field of $F$.

> My attempts

since hypersurfaces occur frequently in multivariable calculus as level sets $F(x, y, z,w) = c$,

so $xy+xz-xyz+xyzw-c=0$.
It follows that in this case the gradient of $F$ is orthogonal to the level sets of $F$.

Then the gradient of F is then normal to the hypersurface,

$N=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z},\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\right)=(y+z-yz+yzw,y-xz+xzw,x-xy-xyw,xyz)$

Comment: You need the gradient of $F$ for the [normal](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)). Once you have the normal vector field, the tangent vector field is perpendicular to it.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused . Thanks for the comment, can I consider $$N=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x},\frac{\partial F}{\partial y},\frac{\partial F}{\partial z},\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}\right)$$ is  normal vector field of F

Comment: Yes - exactly right!